# Handle Multiple Thread (Same Function) Wait Notify

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, wait, notify

I'm having a problem with my MultiThread, cause It unable to work independently, however, there are 2 different thread. In wait and notify

My Main Class:

```
    Mechanics mechanics = new Mechanics(busShop, "Mechanic 1");
    Mechanics mechanics2 = new Mechanics(busShop, "Mechanic 2");

    Thread thMechanic = new Thread(mechanics);
    Thread thMehanic2 = new Thread(mechanics2);

    thMechanic.start();
    thMehanic2.start();
```

Two Different Independent thread is created, now what I do it this:

My Mechanics Class:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    fixEngine();
}

private void fixEngine() {
    while (true) {
        busShop.FixEngine(MechanicsName);
    }
}
```

When run, just execute this function unlimited:

```
public void FixEngine(String mechanicsName) {
    //Call mechanics to fix engine
    Bus bus;
    synchronized (EntryRamp.ListBusDepotWaiting) {
        while (EntryRamp.ListBusDepotWaiting.size() == 0) {
            try {
                EntryRamp.ListBusDepotWaiting.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    synchronized (ListBusEngineFix) {
        //Fix the mechanics


        bus = (Bus) ((LinkedList<?>) EntryRamp.ListBusDepotWaiting).poll();
        ((LinkedList<Bus>) ListBusEngineFix).offer(bus);
        System.out.println("Bus: " + bus.getBusName() + "is being fixed by" + mechanicsName);



        ListBusEngineFix.notify();
        //Done fix
    }


}
```

And where are the notify comes from here.

```
    synchronized (ListBusDepotWaiting) {
        //If depot is not 2
        if (ListBusDepotWaiting.size() < 2 && ListBusRamp.size() == 0) {
            //If empty we can start moving
            bus = (Bus) ((LinkedList<?>) ListBusWaiting).poll();
            ((LinkedList<Bus>) ListBusRamp).offer(bus);
            System.out.println("RAMP: " + bus.getBusName() + "Enter the RAMP");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            bus = (Bus) ((LinkedList<?>) ListBusRamp).poll();
            ((LinkedList<Bus>) ListBusDepotWaiting).offer(bus);
            System.out.println("DEPOT: " + bus.getBusName() + "Enter the DEPOT");
            ListBusDepotWaiting.notify();
        }
    }
```

When Run it shows this:

```
RAMP: Bus 1Enter the RAMP
DEPOT: Bus 1Enter the DEPOT
RAMP: Bus 2Enter the RAMP
DEPOT: Bus 2Enter the DEPOT
Bus: Bus 1is being fixed byMechanic 1
RAMP: Bus 3Enter the RAMP
Bus: Bus 1being cleaned
Bus: Bus 2is being fixed byMechanic 2
```

Bus 1 does not handle immediately, but it waits for bus 2 to come, and work together with another thread. this means thread 1 unable to do itself, you might not see here, but both mechanics 1 and mechanics 2 finish at a same time, while mechanics 1 given the task first. Any idea guys?

Comment: Or is it better to avoid the CPU automatic task, just manual assign odd number of the bus go to mechanics 1, even number goes to mechanics 2. Is it better cause we have control, or is it better alternative in order to automate?